# TikZ to PDF from the command line

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation, matlab

I am generating TikZ files using figures from MATLAB (using a MATLAB function from the stack exchange). I then open these files using TikzEdt, and generate the PDF file. Is there a way to make it automatically, that is to say, using some commands, generate the PDF file?

Comment: Which operating system do you have, Windows, Linux, OS X? Edit: Oh, and do you mean `matlab2tikz`?

Comment: I am in Windows, and yes the function is matlab2tikz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Updated answer -- standalone

(Note: I haven't tested this updated part of the answer, with the `standalone` option. Will remove this message when I have.)

`matlab2tikz` has an option `standalone` that generates a complete, compilable file with the `standalone` documentclass. Hence, by doing

```
matlab2tikz('test.tikz','standalone',true)
```

the resulting file can be compiled directly, so on the command line one can do

```bsh
pdflatex test.tikz
```

If you want to do this with all `.tikz` files in a folder, you can loop over all the files. This can be done directly in Matlab, or you can do it via the command line. Below is an example for bash. It may however be more convenient to do this on a per plot-basis, so you could define a simple Matlab-function that does this for you.

### Via Matlab

#### Function

Save the following as `plotviatikztopdf.m`:

```ml
function plotviatikztopdf(filename,varargin)
% Generate a LaTeX file using matlab2tikz and compile
% this directly to PDF with pdflatex, cleaning up temporary
% files after compilation.
%
%    PLOTVIATIKZTOPDF(FILENAME,VARARGIN)
% FILENAME is the name of the generated LaTeX file, with file ending,
% e.g. THING.TEX. VARARGIN is (optional) arguments to matlab2tikz,
% such as definitions of width and height.

% strip file ending
ind = find(filename=='.',1,'last');
basename = filename(1:ind-1);

% run matlab2tikz
matlab2tikz(filename,'standalone',true,varargin{:})

% run pdflatex on generated file
command = sprintf('pdflatex %s', filename);
system(command);

% remove .aux and .log files
if ispc
    system(sprintf('del "%s.aux"',basename));
    system(sprintf('del "%s.log"',basename));
elseif isunix
    system(sprintf('rm %s.aux %s.log',basename,basename));
end
```

After creating your plot, execute

```ml
plotviatikztopdf('mylovelyplot.tikz')
```

to save the generate the `.tikz` file and convert it to PDF. You can also specify the width and height (as specific lengths, not commands), e.g.

```ml
plotviatikztopdf('mylovelyplot.tikz','width','10cm','height','10cm')
```

#### All files in folder

You can actually do this from within Matlab itself, at least it worked for my simple test case. I tested this in a Linux environment, if Matlab handles things differently in other operating systems it may not work. (This isn't very pretty.)

```ml
cd /path/to/tikz/files

files = dir('*.tikz');

for k = 1:length(files)
    ind = find(files(k).name=='.',1,'last');
    basename = files(k).name(1:ind-1);
    if ispc
        command = sprintf('pdflatex %s', filename);
    elseif isunix
        command = sprintf('pdflatex %s', filename);
    end
    system(command);
end
```

### Terminal

If you are on Linux (probably works in OS X as well) you can try the following shell script. It uses the same idea as above (assuming you are in the correct folder):

```bsh
for f in *.tikz
do 
  jn=$(basename $f .tikz)
  pdflatex $f
  rm $jn.aux $jn.log
done
```

Save it as e.g. `runtikz.sh`, make it executable with `chmod u+x runtikz.sh`, and run it with `./runtikz.sh` in the terminal.

---

## Old answer

I assume you use `matlab2tikz` to generate the `.tikz` files. This generates a `tikzpicture` with an `axis` environment from `pgfplots`, so the minimal LaTeX code needed to compile it is usually

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\input{file.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Assuming no libraries are required, and you haven't specified width/height as commands, as suggested by `matlab2tikz`. `amsmath` is needed because `matlab2tikz` uses `\text` from `amsmath` (or `amstext`) for axis labels.

Now, you can write code directly as an argument to `pdflatex` on the command line, so you can do

```bsh
pdflatex -jobname test "\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\begin{document}\input{test.tikz}\end{document}"
```

If you want to do this with all `.tikz` files in a folder, you can loop over all the files. This can be done directly in Matlab, or you can do it via the command line. Below is an example for bash. It may however be more convenient to do this on a per plot-basis, so you could define a simple Matlab-function that does this for you.

### Via Matlab

#### Function

Save the following as `plotviatikztopdf.m`:

```ml
function plotviatikztopdf(filename,varargin)

matlab2tikz(filename,varargin{:})

ind = find(filename=='.',1,'last');
basename = filename(1:ind-1);
if ispc
    command = sprintf('pdflatex -jobname %s "\\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\begin{document}\\input{%s}\\end{document}"',basename,filename);
elseif isunix
    command = sprintf('pdflatex -jobname %s "\\\\documentclass{standalone}\\\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\\\begin{document}\\\\input{%s}\\\\end{document}"',basename,filename);
end
system(command);
if ispc
    system(sprintf('del "%s.aux"',basename));
    system(sprintf('del "%s.log"',basename));
elseif isunix
    system(sprintf('rm %s.aux %s.log',basename,basename));
end
```

There is a difference in how Windows and Linux handles backslashes in a command line, I guess because Windows uses the backslash to separate directories. When I did this in Linux I needed to send the string `\\documentclass{standalone}...` to the terminal via `system`, and to print a backslash in the format string with `sprintf` you have to escape it with a second backslash (`sprintf('\ab')` will just print `b`, `sprintf('\\ab')` will print `\ab`). That is the reason for the quadruple backslashes seen above. In Windows however, there is no need to handle backslashes in the command any special way, so the `command` string can be `\documentclass...`, so you just need two backslashes.

In the above function I added a check for OS, and it worked fine on my small test on a Windows machine.

After creating your plot, execute

```
plotviatikztopdf('mylovelyplot.tikz')
```

to save the generate the `.tikz` file and convert it to PDF. You can also specify the width and height (as specific lengths, not commands), e.g.

```
plotviatikztopdf('mylovelyplot.tikz','width','10cm','height','10cm')
```

#### All files in folder

You can actually do this from within Matlab itself, at least it worked for my simple test case. I tested this in a Linux environment, if Matlab handles things differently in other operating systems it may not work. (This isn't very pretty.)

```
cd /path/to/tikz/files

files = dir('*.tikz');

for k = 1:length(files)
    ind = find(files(k).name=='.',1,'last');
    basename = files(k).name(1:ind-1);
    if ispc
        command = sprintf('pdflatex -jobname %s "\\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\begin{document}\\input{%s}\\end{document}"',basename,filename);
    elseif isunix
        command = sprintf('pdflatex -jobname %s \\\\documentclass{standalone}\\\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\\\begin{document}\\\\input{%s}\\\\end{document}',basename,filename);
    end
    system(command);
end
```

### Terminal

If you are on Linux (probably works in OS X as well) you can try the following shell script. It uses the same idea as above (assuming you are in the correct folder):

```bsh
for f in *.tikz
do 
  jn=$(basename $f .tikz)
  pdflatex -jobname $jn "\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\begin{document}\input{$f}\end{document}"
  rm $jn.aux $jn.log
done
```

Save it as e.g. `runtikz.sh`, make it executable with `chmod u+x runtikz.sh`, and run it with `./runtikz.sh` in the terminal.

Comment: When I execute the command

     pdflatex -jobname test "\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document}\input{SuddenAreaChangeFlowChart.tikz}\end{document}"

I get the following error in Matlab:

    <Undefined function 'pdflatex' for input arguments of type 'char'.>

Can any one give a suggestion please?

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. Try writing a `!` before the command, to run external programs from the Matlab terminal you have to "escape" to the system terminal with a  `!`. Did you try the function I defined?

Comment: The ! did work (partially), and it generated only the *.aux and .*log files then stoped...
Regarding the function that you suggested, it executes without error but no pdf is produced. here is the output:
>> plotviatikztopdf('SuddenAreaChangeFlowChart.tikz')
 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) 
pdflatex: Windows API error 53: The network path was not found.  
pdflatex: Data: \\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots}\\begin{document}\\input{SuddenAreaChangeFlowChart.tikz}\\end{document}.tex

Comment: @user2536125 Ok. I'll get access to a computer with Windows 7, MikTeX and Matlab tomorrow, so I'll test it then. As mentioned I only tested this on a Linux system, and there it worked fine, could be some differences between operating systems. But I'll check back tomorrow. You could also test to do the same from a command prompt, not from within Matlab.

Comment: T  Ok, will do and let you know.

Comment: @user2536125 I updated my answer a bit, just needed to cut down the number of backslashes in the `command` string.

Comment: The execution of the modified function stops with the following output:
`! Undefined control sequence. 
\pgfplots@label@ ->$\lambda {}_{\text  
                                      {in}}$ 
l.1372 \end{axis}`
And I also noticed that it is taking a very long time, not to mention the auxiliary files...I guess the most optimal solution will be matlab2tikz then TikzEdt to generate quickly and simply the PDF files !

Comment: @user2536125 The `amsmath` package is missing (had forgotten that `matlab2tikz` uses that), change `usepackage{pgfplots}` to `usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}`.

Comment: @user2536125 Added deletion of the `.aux` and `.log` files to the function. Worked fine on Linux, can test on Windows tomorrow if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It is working perfectly and quickly...I will reference your answer in the Mathworks exchange website. Thanks alot for your help @Torbjørn T

Comment: I tried to modify the line `command = sprintf(' pdflatex -output-directory=',strcat(pathstr,'\PDF'), '-jobname %s \\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\begin{document}\\input{%s}\\end{document}',basename,filename);`

so the PDF will be written in the PDF directory(I already assigned a value to pathstr). Can you please tell me what is wrong with the command? as it just sort of stops, but no error and files PDF is generated.

Comment: @user2536125 You're using `sprintf` wrong (just check what the `command` string becomes), try `sprintf('pdflatex -output-directory=%s%s -jobname %s \\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\begin{document}\\input{%s}\\end{document}',pathstr,'\PDF',basename,filename)`.