# label font size in matlab->matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize, matlab, matlab2tikz

Does anyone knoy how can we increase the labels fontsize when we use the matlab2tikz [(see this link)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) function from the mathworks file exchange? I always have to access the *.tikz generated file and then add an insctruction to increase the font. Can't that be done as an input to the mat2tikz function?

**UPDATE**: Using the suggested solution by **Torbjørn T**, the function matlab2tikz does modify the labels fontsize, however, since I am using nested functions in the following manner (to generate the PDF version):

```
plotviatikztopdf(strcat(filename,'PPT','.tikz'),'standalone', true,'extraAxisOptions','label style={font=\Large}')
    function plotviatikztopdf(filename,varargin)

matlab2tikz(filename,varargin)


%%
ind = find(filename=='.',1,'last');
basename = filename(1:ind-1);
if ispc
    command = sprintf(' pdflatex -jobname %s \\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\begin{document}\\input{%s}\\end{document}',basename,filename);
elseif isunix
    command = sprintf(' pdflatex -jobname %s \\\\documentclass{standalone}\\\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\\\begin{document}\\\\input{%s}\\\\end{document}',basename,filename);
end

system(command);

if ispc
    system(sprintf('del "%s.aux"',basename));
    system(sprintf('del "%s.log"',basename));

    %%moving to required directory
elseif isunix
    system(sprintf('rm %s.aux %s.log',basename,basename));
end
```

sozrce of the above function [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135912/tikz-to-pdf-from-the-command-line)
The output is ignoring the `'ExtraAxisOptions'` . Is there something wrong in my `varargin`?

Thanks.

Comment: Just axis labels, or ticklabels, titles, legends as well? Does adding `\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large}}` to the preamble of your `.tex` file help?

Comment: When I add it manually to the resulting *.tikz file, it does work, however, using { matlab2tikz(strcat(filename,'PPT','.tikz'),'extraCode','\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large}}') } which is supposed to add exactly the same piece of code at the beginning of the generated file, is not working. I mean, it is not added at all to the generated file.

Comment: I didn't mean adding it to the `.tikz` file, but to the `.tex` file where you `\input` the `.tikz`. Then you only have to add it once, and if you want to change it, you only have to change it one place.

Comment: Actually, I have written a small function in Matlab, which c alls the matlab2tikz function, and generates directly the PDF versions as well. The function takes the figure, generates a PDF version for a report, then, edits the fontsize, and generates a PDF version for presentations. Hence, there is no \input{} .

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the `'standalone'` option, I assume you're using that. You could try adding the `label style` to `'extraAxisOptions'`, i.e. `'extraAxisOptions','label style={font=\Large}'`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the help, Please check my update.

Comment: That function looked oddly familiar ... With the standalone option it shouldn't be necessary to have `sprintf(' pdflatex -jobname %s \\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}\\begin{document}\\input{%s}\\end{document}',basename,filename);`. The point of that option is that it generates a compilable file, so including preamble. I'd think that simply `sprintf('pdflatex %s',filename)` should be sufficient.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. sorry, I forgot to add a link to the function. It was written and corrected by you eventually !  And I still think I have to use the complet command, otherwise, I get the error :{! LaTeX Error: Environment tikzpicture undefined. }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11641/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-user2536125)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I [first wrote that function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135924/586) I thought I had tested with optional arguments as well, but it seems it doesn't work after all. To fix that change the first line of `plotviatikztopdf` to

```
matlab2tikz(filename,varargin{:})
```

i.e. just add `{:}` at the end of `varargin`.

To use `'standalone',true` the preamble and `document` environment has to be removed from the `command` string, so change that to `sprintf('pdflatex %s',filename)` (untested).

(I'll update my other answer later.)